# wordpress get current permalink or url without domain

Tags: wordpress, multilingual, permalinks

I'm not sure if I titled this correctly but this is my issue, I have to create 2 same exact blogs and the only difference is language.  So but what I need is at the top when clicked on a language it would take the user to that same page but in the language he/she clicked on.

I'm using permalinks currently and I've tried the following:

```
<?php 
   function my_permalink() {
    echo substr(get_permalink(), strlen(get_option('home')));
   }

   my_permalink();
?>
```

but that for some reason on my home page points to a post and not the home page.  I believe that works in posts but I need that to also work on the home.  Here's the links to both blogs, any help is much appreciated..

English:  http://www.inblu.pe/prblog/
Spanish:  http://www.inblu.pe/prbloges/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be more simple with standard PHP method :

```
$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]
```

Of course it will work for current post only.

You can also use that :

```
<?php 
   function my_permalink() {
    echo substr(get_permalink(), strlen(home_url('/')));
   }

   my_permalink();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about the_permalink? I'm fighting with that now.

~ Justin